# How do I get table attributes (PostgreSQL 12+) with a description?

Tags: sql, postgresql, attributes, postgis

I want to get attributes with related objects: schema, table, name, type, PK, notnull, unique, index, constraint, sequence.
My query duplicates attributes if multiple index, constraint, or sequence are associated with them...
How do I avoid this?
At the same time, I would like index, constraint, and sequence to be arrays...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_attributes
AS SELECT
    ns.nspname AS "schema",
    ct.oid AS "tablerelid",
    ct.relname AS "tablename",
    a.attrelid AS "relid",
    a.attname AS "name",
    a.attnum AS "num",
    ( a.atttypid::regtype ) AS "type",
    a.atttypmod AS "typemod",
    ( CASE WHEN ( a.atttypid::regtype )::text = 'geometry' THEN postgis_typmod_type(a.atttypmod) END ) AS "typegeom",
    ( CASE WHEN ( a.atttypid::regtype )::text = 'geometry' THEN postgis_typmod_srid(a.atttypmod) END ) AS "typesrid",
    ia.indisprimary AS "pk",
    a.attnotnull AS "notnull",
    ia.indisunique AS "unique",
    ci.relname AS "index",
    cr.conname AS "constraint",
    pg_get_serial_sequence(quote_ident(ct.relname), quote_ident(a.attname)) AS "sequence"
FROM
    pg_attribute a
    LEFT JOIN pg_class ct ON ct.oid = a.attrelid
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = ct.relnamespace
    LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace ts ON ts.oid = ct.reltablespace
    LEFT JOIN pg_index ia ON ia.indrelid = a.attrelid AND a.attnum = ANY(ia.indkey)
    LEFT JOIN pg_class ci ON ci.oid = ia.indexrelid
    LEFT JOIN pg_constraint cr ON cr.conrelid = a.attrelid AND cr.conkey @> ARRAY[a.attnum]
WHERE
    ns.nspname != 'information_schema'
    AND ns.nspname != 'pg_catalog'
    AND ns.nspname != 'tiger'
    AND ns.nspname != 'tiger_date'
    AND ns.nspname != 'topology'
    AND ct.relname != 'pointcloud_formats'
    AND ct.relname != 'spatial_ref_sys'
    AND ct.relname NOT LIKE 'pg_temp_%'
    AND ct.relkind = ANY( ARRAY['r'::"char", 'p'::"char"] )
    AND a.attnum > 0
    AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY
    lower(ns.nspname),
    lower(ct.relname),
    a.attnum;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `GROUP BY` clause with **all** the columns that are unique, like `a.attnum` or `ct.relname`. For the other columns, use an aggregate function like `string_agg` or `array_agg`.

I cannot say how useful is to get a row that has `unique` as `{f,t,f}`, but if you want to present the information in a different form, you'd have to change the query as such.